# SharePoint - enterprise search - number of results for a single user

Tags: enterprise-search

Is there a way for a single user with only read rights to specify number of results in a search site? web part?

Explained in another way. 
User "test" wants to specify number of results to display in a search. He want's to specify ex: 10 -25 - 50 results per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, no. But that would not be too hard to create yourself.

1. Add a custom web part with a drop down for your page size options. You *could* even do this with SharePoint designer I guess.
2. When the user changes the dropdown value, reload the page and append something like ?pagesize=50 to the URL
3. Use the parameter for the pagesize property of the core results webpart. I'm not sure if you can do this in XML, but otherwise you can inherit the core results web part class and implement a little piece of code which does this.